# Javascript pushing operators to a stack from a string

Tags: javascript, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am currently writing a program in Javascript where the user enters in an infix notation expression as a string which will then be converted to postfix notation. I'm having trouble pushing each operator to the stack. Below are the two main portions of code pertinent to my question.

```
var input = readLine();
postfixCalc(input);

//main function that converts an infix notation function to postfix
function postfixCalc (input) {
  var operatorStack = new Stack();
  print("length of input: " + input.length);//DEBUG
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (isOperator(input[i])) {
      operatorStack.push(input[i]);
      print("Pushing to stack: " + input[i]);//DEBUG
    } else {
      print("Not an operator: " + input[i]);//DEBUG
    }
    print("This is what the input character is: " + input[i]);//DEBUG
  }
}

//This function takes the current character being looked at in postfixCalc
//and returns true or false, depending on if the current character is 
//a valid operator
function isOperator(y) {
  //if y is a valid operator, return true.
  if (y===("+" || "-" || "*" || "/" || "(" || ")")) {
    print("What is being looked at: " + y);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Only the first character compared in this line
    if (y===("+" || "-" || "*" || "/" || "(" || ")")) {
 from a given string is pushed to the stack. The string I've been using to test with has been "3*5+6". Any thoughts as to why this might be?

Comment: `y===("+" || "-" || "*" || "/" || "(" || ")"))` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check

```
 y===("+" || "-" || "*" || "/" || "(" || ")"))
```

is just

```
y==="+"
```

---

You either needs to break it up as

```
if (y==="+" || y==="-" || ...)
```

or you can use indexOf with an array or sting.

```
if (["+","-","*","/","(",")"].indexOf(y) > -1)
```

or a regular expression